# how to change font color on overlay when hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

When you hover over the navigation links section I  want my overlay to display as a white section  and the font color to change to white. Right now when you hover over navigation it does give me a white section overlay, but I can't figure out how to change the font color too.
I also want to move the overlay down, but can't figure out how to.

```
<body>
  
  <div class="header">
      <div class="top-line">
        <h5>Buy now & pay later with Afterpay</h5>
      </div>
   </div> 
    
    <div class="container">
 
 <div class="info">                    
        <div class="left">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wsCyQ98/Coozy-Shoes-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo">
            
          </div>
        <div class="middle-side">
          <a href="#">Shoes</a>
          <a href="#">Sale</a>
          <a href="#">Our Team</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
          <a href="#">Account</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:36px"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="title"></div>
```

I tried selecting the anchor tag along with the .title class but the anchor tags don't show up. I also tried moving the overlay section down by giving the top a 10px but it doesn't move it down.

```
.title {
      height: 150px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
color: white;
width: 100%;
font-size: 25px;
      /*padding-top: 20px;
padding: 15px 0;*/
text-align: center;
z-index: -1;
transition: 0.8s;
        }

.container:hover .title, a {
z-index: 0;
color: black;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To a better solution, i suggest you to use of jsvascript in your code.

And another point in styling, try `!important` keyword at the end of attribute value to prevent from browser default styles.

```js
        const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');

        function shower() {
            navbar.style.display = 'flex';
        }

        function hider() {
            navbar.style.display = 'none';
        }
```

```css
        .info {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        ul {
            display: flex;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: white;
            display: none;
        }

        ul a li {
            padding: 15px;
        }

        ul a li:hover {
            background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: rgb(255, 0, 234) !important;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: red !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="info">                    
        <img id="back" onmouseout="hider()" onmouseover="shower()" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-grunge-decorative-relief-navy-blue-stucco-wall-texture-wide-angle-rough-colored-background_1258-28311.jpg?w=2000" alt="logo">
            
        <ul id="navbar" onmouseover="shower()">
            <a><li>Home</li></a>
            <a><li>Products</li></a>
            <a><li>Profile</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```